# How to Remove Specific Item from each Object in Generic List

Tags: c#, list, loops, generics, foreach

### Background

I have a list of generic objects. Each generic object has a specific field I need to remove.

I create the list like this.

```
list = new List<Object>();
list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(OutJson, new BooleanJsonConverter());
```

However i need to then remove a item from every object in that list. However i don't know how many or what objects are in the list. I do know that there will always be a field that i need to remove however.

## Pseudocode

I think I need to do something like this, but in a generic way.

```
    //Loop through list objects, and for each object, loop through its 
    //properties. If any of the properties match a string, remove 
    //that property from the object.  

                foreach (var object in list)
                {
                    foreach (var item in object)
                    {
                        if(item.ToUpper() == "SpecificKey")
                        {
                            list.Remove(item);

                        }
                    }

                }
```

### Question

How do I loop through the generic object in a list and remove a specific item if it is present?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What is `var object in list` and what is `var item in item`?

Comment: @DavidG, I've added a comment in the code to explain a little better what i'm trying to do.

Comment: That code won't even compile. Please read [mcve]

Comment: No it was pseudo code,  iIve now marked it as such. Apologies.

Comment: We don't want psuedo code, we want real code to fix.

Comment: Loop through properties of generic object, removing specific item ftom list, all these questions been asked before... It is possible with reflection. Search in google or stackoverflow

Comment: Do you know about [`List.RemoveAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to complete this, it's better to mark the objects as dynamic.

Then this would work.

```
List<dynamic> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(OutJson, new BooleanJsonConverter());

list.RemoveAll(x=>x["SpecificKey"]!=null);
```

Comment: Not sure i can make them Dynamic. Can you explain what the Lambda is doing please?

Comment: If its dynamic, checking if object["Prop"] will return null if it doesnt have it, otherwise it will leave it as it is

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of generic objects. Each generic object has a specific field I need to remove.

If you're trying to access a specific property on an objection, you can use reflection. See the answer here:

[Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

> i need to then remove a item from every object in that list. However i don't know how many or what objects are in the list. I do know that there will always be a field that i need to remove however.

Your pseudocode is code is confusing, but it seems like you're just trying to remove a child from a parent object. If that is the case, and the child is a complex object, then set it equal to `null`.

If you mean to say that you need to any object from the list that contains a property that has the specified property name, then you should know that you cannot remove items from a list while iterating through it using `foreach`. See the answer here:

[C# List - Removing items while looping / iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340757/c-sharp-list-removing-items-while-looping-iterating)